# TFS workflow transition for custom WIT field

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have created custom WIT say Problem. and this problem has one custom field **ProblemStatus** which is having four options **NEW**, **OPEN**, **PLANNED** and **CLOSE**. Now i want to define workflow transition for this custom field.

For Example :

ProblemStatus can set to **OPEN** only if it's current status is **NEW**

ProblemStatus can set to **CLOSE** only if it's current status is **OPEN**

I am able to set workflow transitions for States. But could not find way to set workflow transitions for the Custom field options which I have created.

So How to achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

You are replicating the behavior of the built-in State field. Why do you want to create a new one ?
How would you manage two workflows for the same element (WI) ?

I think you should use the reason field to store this information. There is a built-in feature to manage the list of possible reasons per transition.